# Complex JPQL Query Returning 0 Zero Results Fetching Table Twice in Query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm working on an application where bus drivers have group chats with the parents of children on the routes they handle.

I want to have an option for sending a message to all chats *before* the last stop the bus arrived at.

I've tried this query, but it always returns 0 results. When it should definitely be returning at least one.

```
1 | @Query("select g from GroupChat g " + 
2 |        "join g.route r " +
3 |        "join r.bus b " +
4 |        "join b.mostRecentStop mrs " +
5 |        "join r.stops s " +
6 |        "join s.children c " +
7 |        "where r.routeId = :routeId " +
8 |        "and s.stopTime <= mrs.stopTime " +
9 |        "and g.childId = c.childId ")
10|Set<GroupChat> getAllGroupChatsOnRouteForPreviousStops(@Param("routeId") short routeId);
```

GroupChats PK is routeId-childId

Line 2 fetches the route that the groupchat is associated with.
Line 3 fetches the bus for that route.
Line 4 fetches the most recent stop the bus arrived at.
Line 5 fetches all stops on the route
Line 6 fetches all the children on the route (i.e. each child from each stop)
Line 7 filters for only the queried route.
Line 8 filters for stops before the most recent stop
Line 9 filters for only groupchats for only children on the remaining stops.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` in application.properties. Now, execute this query. You will now be able to the SQL Query in the Application Logger. Go to SQL terminal and execute the same by replacing `?` with `routeId` value. Debug the query line by line from there on.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya so I've given that a try, and weirdly the results I get running the query on mysql workbench is different to that from my application.

Comment: So, do you get more than 0 results in mysql workbench?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya I get the one row I'm expecting

Comment: Great. So, your query is perfect. Try changing `Set<GroupChat>` to `List<GroupChat>`. Also, try making that query native

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya thanks for sticking with me for this! So I've swapped out for the jpql query for the native query that seems to be working. I tried this with List and Set and both still seem to return nothing.

Comment: Let us continue the discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179998/discussion-between-maruthi-adithya-and-jordan-mackie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this involves a complex query in JPQL, it is better and recommended to use a Native Query.

```
@Query(value="select g from GroupChat g  
              join g.route r  
              join r.bus b 
              join b.mostRecentStop
              join r.stops s
              join s.children c 
              where r.routeId = :routeId
              and s.stopTime <= mrs.stopTime
              and g.childId = c.childId",
              nativeQuery=true
      )
Set<GroupChat> getAllGroupChatsOnRouteForPreviousStops(@Param("routeId") short routeId);
```

Comment: Managed to remove a join by using a native query and fix the problem! thank you!